# Telephony API not working properly in Android2.3

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I am working on application which will use the Telephony API.
I am using:

```
Context context = getBaseContext();
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
try {
  Class<?> c = Class.forName(tMgr.getClass().getName());             
  Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
  method.setAccessible(true); 

  ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(tMgr);
  telephonyService.silenceRinger();
  telephonyService.answerRingingCall();  
} catch (Exception e) {
  // exception handling
}
```

This code is used to auto answer call, and works fine in Android 2.2, but doesn't work in Android 2.3.

Is there any replacement of Telephony API in Android 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

in your case its only the permission that changed from MODIFY_PHONE_STATE to READ_PHONE_STATE and if you want to accerss if via broadcastreceiver from outside your app, you'll need permission GET_TASK too ....